# Is the Insanity Workout worth it?

Tags: workout-routines, nutrition, home-exercise

I'm 18, average height and quite skinny - not a fan of the whole idea of going to a gym to lift weights, and not after getting *big*, just fit.

Is the Insanity workout a good approach? If it is, should I be following the diet it recommends (including the protein powder)?

Comment: This one? http://www.beachbody.com/product/fitness_programs/insanity.do If you're just starting to exercise/be physically fit and all that, maybe you should try something less intense like T25 or even less intense like Hip hop abs. I'm not really an expert, but I have friends who are... https://youtu.be/S6j4qcD1fe4?t=93

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is the Insanity workout a good approach?**

If you need to pay for your routine, **no**.

**If it is, should I be following the diet it recommends (including the protein powder)?**

**Absolutely not**. Since you mention that you are quite skinny, what I recommend is eating more than usual (**caloric surplus**). Protein shake should not be your main source of protein.

If you really want to make a change to your body, consider calculating your [TDEE](http://iifym.com/tdee-calculator/).

As far as **protein intake** goes, the usual **1g per pound of bodyweight**. **Fat intake** probably around **0.5 ~ 0.6 g per pound of bodyweight**. Fill up the rest with carbs, vitamins and minerals.

Do note that stated protein intake, fat intake is **not** your final answer. You may need to modify it to ensure that you are able to ensure the best muscle to fat gain ratio.

**EDIT**

After having a long conversation with @Ryan, I would like to suggest that you **opt for a free calisthenics workout program BEFORE buying Insanity**. Once you feel happy doing calisthenics, then you can decide whether you want to buy Insanity or continue with your routine.

Here is some of the free ones for you to try:-

[Nerd's Fitness Beginner Bodyweight Workout](http://www.nerdfitness.com/blog/2009/12/09/beginner-body-weight-workout-burn-fat-build-muscle/)

[Fortress Bodyweight Workout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-qEE3x27PE)

Note that if you are unable to do pull-ups, consider doing incline pull ups and if you are unable to do pistol squat, try doing squats.

[Baristi Workout](http://baristi-workout.com/blog/how-to-get-started-with-calisthenics/)

Comment: ???? Why would someone buy a workout plan when there are tons of free workout plans. Did you even read my post properly????

Comment: Well lets just leave it at that. I for one don't agree that one needs to pay for their workout, even if it is proven to work or not. Those money can be spend on food and other basic necessities as opposed to this. To each their own.

Comment: 18 free games, 12 gifted, rest bought. Here is my view on this, playing games are always fun, and it doesn't have to be video games, most of the games I played are finished. Is it the same for a working out? No, not everyone enjoys doing it. So what I'm saying is that, **IF** he ends up hating or end up not finishing it, or even skipping some of its session, do you think its really worth buying it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24857/discussion-between-aizul-and-ryan).

Comment: Much better answer :) Sorry if I had offended you at all, I can often come off very harsh.

Comment: None taken, lets forget about it and both do our best in answering any future questions.

Comment: I wouldn't discard the **Insanity** workout videos simply because they're not free. All the options you provided didn't really address the **Insanity** routines. These are exercises that are performed at a high tempo continuously for about 40 - 60 minutes. While those options will make the OP fit, they certainly won't give him the same results as the Insanity videos. But then again, Insanity videos are geared towards **weight-loss goals.**

Comment: First off, you are trying to start the same conversation I had with @Ryan which has been resolved. I have already accept the fact that **they can do whatever they want with their money**. Yes, I agree Insanity is basically a HIIT workout. However, OP could do the same to the links that I have provided just by **reducing his rest time, increasing reps done per set**. Yes, I also agree that Insanity is geared towards weight-loss, but at the end of the day, he can still **gain considerable mass with insanity if he choose to eat more**.

Answer (score 1):

***Insanity workout videos*** is a compilation of ***High Intensity Interval Training*** exercises.

#### What Does This Mean?

HIIT exercises are cardio exercises that are designed to burn a lot of calories in the shortest time possible. Its goal isn't to make you big; it's goal is to reduce your weight *(usually fats)* in the shortest time possible.

Unless you're trying to lose weight, Insanity workouts won't benefit you much. This is why if you check the commercials, its target audience are fat people struggling with their weights.

#### That Being Said

If you perform HIIT exercises often, you'll have lots of energy and endurance. So, you won't get tired easily and you certainly won't feel lumpy. It will also give you a toned look because your muscles are active.

If you already have access to the Insanity videos, there's no reason not to try them *(unless you already have lots of energy)*.

The protein powder isn't any different from the supplements people take to increase their protein intake. If you already consume enough protein, you don't need to use protein supplements. You're welcome to take them; they just aren't required.

If your goal is to gain muscles and not be skinny, Insanity videos isn't really for you. If you want to be fit, it's an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

No. You're confusing the look of people who've gone to the gym for 10 years with the effects of going to the gym.

If you're naturally skinny, you won't pack on huge amounts of muscle, in fact, no one does, but especially not skinny people.

Getting big takes many years.

Comment: What does this have to do with Insanity workout's effectiveness?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm 18, average height and quite skinny - not a fan of the whole idea of going to a gym to lift weights, and not after getting big, just fit.
>
> Is the Insanity workout a good approach? If it is, should I be following the diet it recommends (including the protein powder)?

Insanity (and P90X) are both good programs. I'm not familiar with the diet specifically but if you're quite skinny then you might need to increase it. I would say purchase it, follow the diet as well as the workouts, if you don't see the results you're after then adjust your macronutrients as necessary (most likely increase since the standard diet might be geared more towards weight loss, maybe they have different options though?). Just don't go by the scale, don't even look at the scale if you're just getting started. Go by how you look, how you feel, how your clothing is fitting.

You will definitely struggle when starting Insanity but if you stick with it you will get fit. It's some serious bodyweight HIIT (High Intensity Interval Training).